# Psql Docker: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, docker, psql

I created a container using following command:

```
docker run -itd --name jkdb -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123 -v /home/lchang/jkrug/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -p 5532:5432 -d postgres
```

I checked in container and psql does listen to 5432 in container.

However, when I try to connect from my host by following command, I got an error:

```
psql -p 5532 -U postgres
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5532"?
```

I searched many posts but none of them is same with my case. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It does not make any sense but after I specify the host IP is `0.0.0.0` I can connect to docker.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me `psql -h 0.0.0.0 --username=userName databaseName`

Answer (score 2):

Same issue. I am running postgres with docker.

```
docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxx -d -p 5432:5432 --name postgres postgres:11.10
```

can't connect with command `psql postgres postgres`, but was able to connect with command `psql -h 0.0.0.0 postgres postgres`. Don't understand the reason, but hope it helps you.